# Kivymd Reference error when using MDToolbar

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
<Screen3>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Home"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback()]]
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            ScrollView:
                size_hint:0.8,0.7
                do_scroll_x:False
                do_scroll_y:True
                GridLayout:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:self.minimum_height
                    cols:1
                    spacing:10
                    padding:10
                    id:gr

'''
Builder.load_string(KV)

class Screen3(MDScreen):
    pass

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Screen3(name='screen3'))
        return screen_manager

Test().run()
```

This is my basic code right now. For some reason the reference error is caused by the left_action_items option. When I remove it the code works. I honestly have no idea what causes this issue.

Comment: You haven't defined a `callback()` method in your `Test` class.

Comment: Oh crap. When I ran the code without the anchorlayout and everything within, it worked even without the callback code, so I thought it was fine. Thanks for the help, and could you explain what exactly happens ?

Comment: Don't know what is happening other than you cannot call a method that doesn't exist.